# How do I access a numpy array using the memory index?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning numpy and I came across an example that uses `np.nditer`:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
for i in np.nditer(a):
    print i,
```

This prints out:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Which is the memory index of each element. Given these indexes, how can I access each element in the numpy array? Just doing `a[i]` gives an error, as the array has more than 1 dimension.

Comment: "Which is the memory index of each element" - what the heck gave you that idea?

Comment: Iterating over `np.nditer(a)` gives you the (scalar) elements of `a`, not the "memory index" of each element.

Comment: @user2357112 umm....from the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#using-an-external-loop "Observe that with the default of keeping native memory order, the iterator is able to provide a single one-dimensional chunk, whereas when forcing Fortran order, it has to provide three chunks of two elements each". Some people are so rude :(. I clearly said in the question I'm learing numpy, so my terminology may be off.

Comment: Sam, you should get used to reading the content, not the tone of the advice you are given when learning programming. While @user2357112 is not being especially sensitive, he is not being particularly rude either. Notice that the point he is making is 100% factually accurate, so getting worked up over unfortunate phrasing only hurts you by letting emotion get in the way of your learning.

Comment: I am not saying that nothing should offend you, just to consider raising your tolerance a bit.

Comment: I mean, the answer gives little context so in addition to being rude, it's also not very helpful...

Comment: Actually, the second comment pretty much answers your question, although more succinctly than you may be accustomed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nditer` returns elements of the array, as 0d arrays themselves.  You have to use extra parameters to get the (multi)index.

If I do your iteration, but display information about the `i` besides it's value, you'll see:

```
In [132]: a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [134]: for i in np.nditer(a):
     ...:     print(i, type(i), i.shape, i.dtype)

0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> () int32
1 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> () int32
2 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> () int32
3 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> () int32
4 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> () int32
5 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> () int32
```

Or equivalently, using the `repr` display:

```
In [135]: for i in np.nditer(a):
     ...:     print(repr(i))
     ...:     
array(0)
array(1)
...
```

`np.nditer` isn't a very useful iteration mechanism, especially not at the beginning.  It is best seen as a stepping stone toward using it in advanced `cython` code.  In other words, study https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html, all the way to the end.

---

Looks like your example comes from this page.

> The most basic task that can be done with the nditer is to visit every element of an array. Each element is provided one by one using the standard Python iterator interface.

---

There are more direct ways of iterating through an array:

```
In [136]: for i in a: print(repr(i))   # by rows
array([0, 1, 2])
array([3, 4, 5])

In [139]: for ij in np.ndenumerate(a):   # with value and 2d index
     ...:     print(ij)
((0, 0), 0)
((0, 1), 1)
((0, 2), 2)
((1, 0), 3)
((1, 1), 4)
((1, 2), 5)
```

The `multi_index` example on the `nditer` page provides similar information:

```
In [141]: it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'])
     ...: while not it.finished:
     ...:     print("%d <%s>" % (it[0], it.multi_index))
     ...:     it.iternext()
     ...: 
0 <(0, 0)>
1 <(0, 1)>
2 <(0, 2)>
3 <(1, 0)>
4 <(1, 1)>
5 <(1, 2)>
```